# cherrypy page handler returning a combo response with both string and bytes object

Tags: cherrypy

I'm using Cherrypy to build my web application server. In one page handler my response body is in this format:

```
{
  "fileId": "=+afeincas340t5u3tg9",
  "fileBody": ...(some bytes here)
}
```

I cannot use `json.dumps` as the `bytes` part is not json serializable. How can I return this in my page handler and return it to the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can serialize the binary content of the file with base64.

```python
import base64

response = json.dumps({
   "fileId": "=+afeincas340t5u3tg9",
   "fileBody": base64.standard_b64encode(b"some bytes").decode()
 })
```

In the client side (js) you can obtain the original bytes with the [atob function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob).

Comment: Great point, where did you gain this knowledge by the way? I couldn't find this from Cherrypy's documentation.

Comment: Also if the `fileBody` part is to be consumed by html <img>, do I still need to convert it back to bytes using `atob`? Thanks.

Comment: This is unrelated to CherryPy. Just normal Python. As for `<img>`, you'll probably need to construct a data-image URI.